# Segment event documents based on time series and event code

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection in mongoDB that deposit the signal information sent out from machines every N minutes. Each document in the collection has the device SN code and event array which follows the following format:

```
{
  "Device_SN": "ABCDE",
  "Event": [{
             "Code":  200,    
             "DTTM": ISODate("2018-08-21T15:46:50Z")
          },
      {
             "Code":  215,    
             "DTTM": ISODate("2018-08-21T15:46:50Z")
          }
   ] 

}
```

Now, I need to summarize all event history for each device within a certain time range. The output  of my query result must include the device_sn, the event code,  event start time,  event end time and the time duration in a tabular format. To do so, first I need to sort by Event.DTTM and then group succesive events with the same event code(or event code array) together. I guess an additional variable X would be needed that, for instance, increases whenever the Event code alters in the time sereis and further group by that variable.

My query is as following:

```
    db.event.aggregate( [

    { $unwind: "$Event"},
    { $match: { "Event.DTTM":{$gte:ISODate("2019-01-21T08:00:00Z"), $lt:ISODate("2019-01-21T20:00:00Z")} } },
    { $group: { _id:{dsn:"$Device_SN", Code:"$Event.Code"}, dsn:{$first:"$Device_SN"}, Event_Code:{$first:"$Event.Code"}, count:{$sum:1}, event_start_time:{$min:"$Event.DTTM"}, event_end_time:{$max:"$Event.DTTM"} } },
    { $sort: { _id:1, start_time:1}}

 ])
```

However, this is not the result I want. The event should be grouped once the event code alters in the time series. Moreover, the (`end_time`) of an event should be the time on which the event code alters.

I'm a newbie to MongoDB.  Can anyone give me the correct query statement. Any help is appreciated. Thank you very much.

Comment: can you update that doc? it doesnot seem to have all the fields like `Category`, and also if possible can you add a expected output which you want?
i'm not able to get what you actually asking for.

Comment: Oh. sorry. That was a typo. "Category" refers to "Code".  What I acutally need is to first sort by DTTM and then group by sussesive Event Code together.

Comment: The expected output format looks like:  { [ Device_SN, Event_Code, event_start_time, event_end_time, duration] }